# How to set flutter button tap without putting my finger up?

Tags: android, flutter

i am trying to create a xylophone app and write a function.

```
Expanded playSound({Color color, int soundNumber}) {
return Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
    color: color,
    onPressed: () {
      final player = AudioCache();
      player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
    },
  ),
);
```

}

And created multiple buttons on screen, but issue is to tap each button i must have to take my finger up and then tap next button.
how can i set behavior of button or use another widget to automatically tap if swipe finger in one GO.
means if i take my finger to button 1 and keep swiping all button all button should play sounds.

Any ideas?